# Write NOTEmpty Cells multiple times

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that contains days from 06.01 to 08.31 with empty rows and dates inside with 5 Clumns.

I want the days written multiple times under each other like, I set the day for example 3

```
if 06.01 isnt empty
06.01
06.01
06.01
if 06.02 is empty then it doesnt write anything
if 06.03 isnt empty than
06.03
06.03
06.03
```

Every Column has different multiplier.

May Code is:

```
Sub Makro()
    '
    ' Makro3 Makro

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, g As Integer, h As Integer

    'i is the Rows of the dates
    'j the multipler
    'g where the macro should write the multiplied dates
    'h is the Column

    g = 105

    For h = 9 To 13    
        For i = 2 To 93
            Do While j = Cells(101, h)
                Cells(g, h).Value = Cells(i, h).Value
                g = g + 1
                j = j + 1
            Loop    
        Next i
    Next h   
End Sub
```

And it doesnt works, anybody can help me with that?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your problem including example input data and desired output. Also please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) and note that *"does not work"* is a completely useless error description. Instead describe what error you get or what your code does versus what you expected it to do.

Comment: To get faster answer s make sure to post your questions in such a way so that it's easily understandable by other OR give some present situation & the final outcome you want. This way you will get answers fast.